# SOAP invalid characters

Tags: .net, xml, web-services, jaxb, xml-serialization

I'm connecting to a .NET WebService from a Java (JaxB) client. I'm trying to pass a SQL-like string in the fields of one of the objects. The other fields of the object seem to serialise just fine. For some reason, this SQL query causes the server to throw an exception.

Here is the content of the payload as it was sent over the wire...

> uniquedata.name='2012'  OR  extract(epoch from (uniquedata.createdDate - to_timestamp('2012', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH/MI/SS')) < 24 * 60 * 60 OR  extract(epoch from (uniquedata.modifiedDate - to_timestamp('2012', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH/MI/SS')) < 24 * 60 * 60

The interesting thing is the presence of < escape sequences.

> javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Server was unable to read request. ---> There is an error in XML document (1, 1073). ---> Filter string contains invalid characters:
>    uniquedata.name='2012'  OR  extract(epoch from (uniquedata.createdDate - to_timestamp('2012', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH/MI/SS')) < 24 * 60 * 60 OR  extract(epoch from (uniquedata.modifiedDate - to_timestamp('2012', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH/MI/SS')) < 24 * 60 * 60

The exception shows that these have been properly unescaped. Still, I would expect these to be the culprit. So I tried correlating the (1,1073) index with the original request, but it does not bear any resemblance to the original packet. I even tried unescaping the < signs, removing the xml header, soap envelope etc. but no luck.

Any ideas what to try next?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the query was being sent correctly, and that it was code within the service that was throwing the error.